# Postman receive all data from Strapi

Tags: get, postman, strapi

I want to ask you kindly for help. I would like to receive all the Strapi data while I am doing a GET request.

Currently in Postman I see that in total there are 4316 objects. I want to receive all of them via a GET request. How can i change this in order not to receive only 25 objects?

Should I change the url somehow?

[image: total4316]

I tried with something like this, but without luck :(

`http://localhost:1337/api/webs?pagination[start][$eq]=0&[limit][$eq]=10000`

Answer (score 3):

This might work

```
/webs?publicationState=live&pagination[page]=1&pagination[pageSize]=9999
```

and

config/api.js

```
module.exports = {
  rest: {
    defaultLimit: 40,
    maxLimit: 9999,
    withCount: true,
  },
};
```

in my nextjs I was able to generate ~300 pages, I used `maxLimit: 3000`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As per their doc [1] the default and maximum values for pagination[limit] can be configured in the ./config/api.js file with the api.rest.defaultLimit and api.rest.maxLimit keys.

[1]
https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/sort-pagination.html#pagination-by-offset